# Why doesn't `exec startx` work in 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, xorg, application-development

I am used to being able to launch a second X session in TTY8 with `exec startx` but instead I'm getting an error:

```
X: user not authorized to run the X server, aborting.
```

And then in TTY 8 I end up with a stuck cursor and no login at all. Just the blinking cursor in the very top left. How to I kick up a second x server so that I can log in as another user there?

#### Update

With help in the comments, I've gotten somewhat farther. From the terminal in an existing xsession, I can do `exec sudo startx` to get a new x session in TTY8, logged in as that user. If I hop to TTY4, log in and do `exec startx` I can get a session, too.

Here's what still isn't working: the session I get is a a working x session but without any launcher, top bar or  Unity window management. So <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> gives me a terminal and I can launch applications from there, but I can't switch between them and if I minimize a window there's no way to get it back.

Comment: From the Ministry of Silly Questions: Does `sudo exec startx` work?

Comment: Then I get `sudo: exec: command not found` but that' makes no sense because exec is a core bash command.

Comment: @Amanda `sudo` does not execute in a shell. It just looks in the `$PATH`. That is why the `exec` is not found. You should try `exec sudo startx`.

Comment: @minerz029 That does work, though it gives me a weird half Unity session (no launcher, no topbar).

Comment: @minerz029 I can get an xsession now, so I think my question is a new one. If you want to post your solution as an answer I'll accept it. thx.

Comment: @Amanda try `sudo unity --replace` or `sudo unity`?

Comment: @ThomasW. The whole `sudo` bit is kind of a distraction -- what I'm actually trying to do is start a second x session with an unprivileged user. The user doesn't have sudo privs.

Comment: @minerz029 `export DISPLAY=:0` just results in `unity` choking.

Comment: Started a new question to trouble shoot the finer points fo launching unity. http://askubuntu.com/questions/403673/how-do-i-launch-unity-in-an-x-session-i-launched-with-startx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, though it lets you run `startx` as root.

`sudo` does not execute in a shell. It just looks in the `$PATH`. That is why the `exec` is not found. You should try

```
exec sudo startx
```

Also, to start Unity you can just try and run the `export DISPLAY=:0; unity` command in a Terminal.

---

Also, just guessing though you can try these commands:

```
sudo startx
export DISPLAY=:0
unity
```

Comment: Adding that to start x as a non-root user, I need to hop to another TTY console, log in and run `startx` there

Comment: "sudo startx" will cause your session (.xinitrc) to run as root, which you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I have a solution for you, try this command

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure x11-common
```

It should be on console users only by default, try to put it on Anybody.

Comment: That doesn't change anything, unfortunately. Though I need to update the question b/c minerz029 got me over one hurdle.